# Use the result of one regular expression in another - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to retrieve some pieces of data from a URL using regular expressions in Javascript.

```js
const url = "/node_modules/@company/dl-atoms-control/README.md";
```

The following RegEx retrieves text preceded by the string "dl-" In this case "atoms":

```js
const molecularTypePlural = url.match(/(?<=dl-)\w+/gm)[0];
```

I now want to use molecularTypePlural in a second RegEx to retrieve the string preceded by "dl-atoms-" which in this case is "control". I can't hard code this because the molecularTypePlural variable will have different values with different URLs. I have tried the below:

```js
const packageNameRegex = new RegExp(`/(?<=dl-${molecularTypePlural}-)\w+/gm`);
const packageName = nodePath.match(packageNameRegex);
```

However the RegEx doesn't return any results. Logging packageNameRegex reveals that  the RegEx seems to be incorrectly formatted:

```
"/\/(?<=dl-atoms-)w+\/gm/"
```

I think it might be a problem with escaping special characters but I'm not 100% sure. Could anyone show me where I'm going wrong. Thanks

Comment: I did see this answer but I don't really understand the example given tbh.

Comment: I think the problem is in how you constructing regex. You use`new Regex(...)` and inside you put string which contains regular expression literal.

Comment: Still returns null.

Comment: Yea, you also need to escape some characters.

Comment: I think smth like this: `new RegExp(\`(?<=dl-${molecularTypePlural}-)\\w+\`, 'gm')`

Comment: I think I'm nearly there with this: const packageNameRegex = new RegExp(`\(\?<\=dl-${molecularTypePlural}-\)\\w\+`, 'gm'); That returns an array of one item with the string I'm after. Thanks very much for your help